# Need help to understand the solution for NP-completness proof (3CNF <= 0-1 integer-programming problem)

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I was trying to solve problem from Cormen page 1100 34.5-2

Given an integer $m * n$ matrix A and an integer $m$-vector $b$, the 0-1 integer- programming problem asks whether there exists an integer $n$-vector $x$ with elements in the set $<0, 1>$ such that $Ax\leq b$. Prove that 0-1 integer programming is NP-complete. (Hint: Reduce from 3-CNF-SAT.)

I do not understand what is 0-1 integer programming problem and what m and n vector mean here... Like what  $Ax\leq b$ means.

Here is solution (I will really appreciate if you can explain me this one..):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $k$-vectors are just vectors with $k$ elements. The IntProg problem is defined by
$$(A,b) \in \mathrm{IntProg} \\
\Leftrightarrow \exists x\in \{0,1\}^n : (Ax)_i \le b_i \forall 1\le i \le m$$
Where $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb R^m$. The RHS of the condition is abbreviated to $Ax \le b$ wich is to be read as "component-wise less than or equal to".

Intuitively IntProg asks if there is a subset of the columns of $A$ such that their sum ($Ax$ sums all the $i$-th columns where $x_i = 1$) is component-wise less than or equal to $b$.
For example $A = (3\ -1\ 2)$ and $b=-1$ is a yes-instance because the choice $x = (0\ 1\ 0)^T$ gives $Ax = -1 \le b$.

If you want to know what a vector and a matrix is, you should consult wikipedia or google.

Comment: I know what vector and matrix is.. but I am still totally unclear with the solution...

Comment: Can you ask a precise question? The only question in the original post asks about the meaning of the notation, wich I explained.

Comment: I am still not clear what is 0-1 integer-programming problem... I cannot make much sense from your pure math explanation. maybe you can add more words to it?

Comment: @PTNPNX I tried. Is this going into the right direction? Always keep in mind that $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ - that's a very important restriction.

Comment: so b can have any integer right? Not only 1, 0?

And we want to know if there is n-vector x such that if we multiply matrix A with vector x we get resulting vector Ax which is pairwise smaller than b ?

Comment: @PTNPNX Correct. Although I allowed both $A$ and $b$ to have real entries. You can also require integer entries without changing the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: Okay, seems I am starting to wrap my brain around this problem. Thank you

Comment: can you explain how we got A as 2 x 4 matrix in the example and how we got b vector? I do not understand where values came from. How we got the last column of A?

Comment: @PTNPNX As a last comment to that: $A$ has four columns because $\psi$ has four variables and two rows because $\psi$ has two clauses. $b$ has the same size as $A$ has rows. How to get the particular entries is explained in-depth in the solution you posted.

Comment: I do not see any explanation how we got b... maybe I am dumb I do not argue on that, but I just do not see it :( pls explain how we got b vector ... please

Comment: @PTNPNX From your post: "$\ldots \le n_i - 1$ where $n_i$ is the number of variables in $C_i$ that appear negated". This RHS is your $b_i$. While we're at it, the $a_{\ldots}$ feed into $A$ in the way specified sic.